# Cannot start Service in API 23

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to experiment with services, and I found this example:
[Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example).
I tried using the accepted answer, and the changes AndroidDev suggested, but I cant get it to work. Based on the fact that none of my Log messages appear, I think that the Service isn't called.

My onCreate method is this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, YourService.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);
    Vibrator v=(Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
    v.vibrate(500);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

the Service is this:

```
package habos.alarmtest;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;


public class YourService extends Service
{
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    String tag="Babis service";
    public void onCreate()
    {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(tag, "oncreate");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.i(tag, "onstartcommand");
    alarm.setAlarm(this);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
{
    alarm.setAlarm(this);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}
}
```

The onStart method is deprecated, but onStartCommand should work.

the manifest is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="habos.alarmtest">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name=".Alarm" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="habos.START_ALARM" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and the alarm is this

```
package habos.alarmtest;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Vibrator;


public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver
{
String tag="Babis alarm";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Log.i(tag, "onreceive");
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();

    // Put here YOUR code.
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example
    Vibrator v=(Vibrator)context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
    v.vibrate(500);

    wl.release();
}

public void setAlarm(Context context)
{
    Log.i(tag,"setalarm");
    AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent("mypackage.START_ALARM");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 30,pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
}

public void cancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
}
```

added 2 more Logs, before and after the startService,the logcat is here: 
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ksdrfzyjb0qafe/logcat.txt?dl=0

(sorry I didn't paste it directly here, the code block didn't work for some reason)

Comment: what error do u get?

Comment: whats on the logcat whan you call `startService` method?

Comment: there are no error messages, but I uploaded the logcat output

Comment: Register the service in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Thanks, now the service starts, but the code still not works. Specifically, the service's onCreate and onStartCommand are called, and the alarm's setAlarm is called, but the Alarm's onReceive isn't. what should I change?